# iPhone Built-in Timer (Clock) App

Tags: iphone, timer, clock

How would one go about recreating the iPhone 'Timer' section of the iPhone built-in 'Clock' app?
I am not asking about specifics (I am a developer and code objective-c, etc), but rather am trying to learn proper design patterns.  I have included a screenshot of the app below.
I understand that the first portion of the app is an UIDatePicker.  What types of objects are the "When Timer Ends" and "Start" buttons?  The "When Timer Ends" portion looks like a UITableViewCell, and the "Start" button looks like a UIButton.  Are all 3 of these objects in one UITableView?  How would one go about creating the gradients belonging to the "When Timer Ends" and "Start" objects?  Are these simply images?  Or are the gradients created Programmatically?

I generally like to stay away from Interface Builder and code my views Programmatically.

Thanks a lot!

[image: iPhone Timer App Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a UITableView here.

In my opinion, there can be a UIDatePicker and 2 UIbuttons. The buttons use 2 different backgrounds - but they are simple custom buttons.

For the **When Timer Ends** there is also a UILabel to display **Digital** as this will change accordingly with the user's selection.

Comment: Are the UIButtons simply images?  Or are they generated on the fly?

Comment: They are simple images. Texts (Start & When Timer Ends) are button's titles. The When Timer Ends title has also a shadow. This are used as titles and not directly on the background-image to be able to change texts accordingly with the device language (internationalization).

Comment: How do you apply a shadow to the buttonTitle?

Comment: Also, how did they make the background behind the entire window?

Comment: So, the first thing is a UIView. After that, you can put a UIImage as a background. On top of them put the other components. For the shadow - you have an option in the UILabel for shadow color and shadow offset.

Comment: Can you point me towards any code to make the background?  Either send me a link, or you could edit your answer. Thanks